# Lower triangular matrices proof.

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that if $A$  is lower triangular and $B_{ij}$   is the matrix that results when the ith row and jth column of $A$ are deleted, then $B_{ij}$   is lower triangular if $i > j.$

Regarding a 4x4 matrix and eliminating the first row and column, what results is another lower triangular matrix. the question asks me to show that that if i > j then $B_{ij}$ is a lower triangluar matrix. but in the 4 x 4 example, when i = j, $B_{ij}$ is a lower triangular still, so is proof by contradtiction not the way to go?

in summary;
 I have found by experiment, when i = j, $B_{ij}$ is still lower triangular
 Also using a 4 x4 matrix as an experiment, when the first row and second column are deleted, what results is another lower triangular matrix. that is when  i < j

finally, when the second row and the first column are deleted, that is i > j, now, this is not lower triangular, since the first row is a row of zeros. This doesnt satisfy the definition of a lower triangular matrix.

Prehaps im not understanding the question, but what is evedent from experiment is that the opposite of what i have to prove is true.
 I hope my definition of a lower triangular is correct;
 that is, each entry to the right of the main diagonal is zero.

Some pointers please, id like to show it is true for a 4 x 4 matrix before going into a general case.

Comment: Certainly $i > j$ is not a necessary condition: For any $i, j$, applying the process to a zero square matrix produces another zero square matrix.

Comment: How about lower triangular matrices?

Comment: The definition of lower triangular matrix is: $a_{ij}=0$ when $i<j$. So the diagonal elements could be zeros.

Comment: So, in all cases, a lower triangular matrix results.